# Choose row from next nearest neighbour where closest doesn't exist

Tags: sql, oracle

I have three tables, one with temperature data with a date, one with buildings nearby the temperature stations, and one with unique ID's for the weather stations and the buildings, plus a ranking of 1, 2, 3 for the three nearest weather stations to the buildings. What I'd like to do is create a join that brings over the date and temperature from the nearest station to each building, and if the nearest station didn't record a temperature on that day then take the temperature from the next nearest weather station.

I'm pretty sure I'd use something like "Ranking = 1 AND NOT EXISTS" but I'm unsure how to tell it I want every date and if it can't find a certain date for a weather station then look at the next nearest one.

The ideal output is every buildings ID to have a temperature record for every date.

The weather table will occasionally be missing data for certain dates at certain sites so what I'd like to do is to go to the next nearest site when a date is missing from the closest site.

Building Table

| UID | TYPE | DESC | Loc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | House | Terrace | London |
| 2 | Apartments | 5 Floors | Manchester |
| 3 | Office | 12 Floors | Birmingham |
| 4 | Workshop | Detached | Glasgow |

Station Table

| UID | Date | Temp | Loc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/01/2018 | 1 | London |
| 2 | 02/01/2018 | 1 | London |
| 3 | 03/01/2018 | 2 | London |
| 4 | 04/01/2018 | 1 | London |

Spatial Join Table

| Build ID | Station ID | Distance | Rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 5km | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 5km | 1 |
| 3 | 3 | 12km | 2 |
| 4 | 4 | 18km | 3 |

Comment: Please provide sample data and the expected result as tables in your question, read also https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide the expected output for your sample data and an English explanation of how you generate your expected output from the sample data (i.e. what logic you use to match stations to buildings on the days when there is no data). I think you will find that your sample data is insufficient to generate the output you want as, in your sample data, there is no concept of distance between buildings and stations other than for the single nearest station to a building.

Comment: The actual distance between station and building isn't what I'm stuck on. I have the information I need there. Its just how to make a query that check the station ranked at 1 for a measurement on every day of the year and if there is a day where station rank 1 doesn't have temp data then check station ranked 2 for that day.

Answer (score 0):

You have not described what you expect the results to be but for your sample data there is a 1-to-1-to-1 correspondence from building-to-spatial-join-to-station and you can simply use an `INNER JOIN` (there is no need to use any rankings):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   building b
       INNER JOIN spatial_join sj
       ON (b."UID" = sj.build_id)
       INNER JOIN station s
       ON (sj.station_id = s."UID")
```

Which, for the sample data, outputs:

| UID | TYPE | DESC | LOC | BUILD_ID | STATION_ID | DISTANCE | RANK | UID | DATE | TEMP | LOC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | House | Terrace | London | 1 | 1 | 5km | 1 | 1 | 2018-01-01 00:00:00 | 1 | London |
| 2 | Apartments | 5 Floors | Manchester | 2 | 2 | 5km | 1 | 2 | 2018-01-02 00:00:00 | 1 | London |
| 3 | Office | 12 Floors | Birmingham | 3 | 3 | 12km | 2 | 3 | 2018-01-03 00:00:00 | 2 | London |
| 4 | Workshop | Detached | Glasgow | 4 | 4 | 18km | 3 | 4 | 2018-01-04 00:00:00 | 1 | London |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/4SrN1h5r)

Comment: Sorry. i wasn't clear.

So the out put would be

Date | BID | Temperature 

For every day of the year and every building. Where a date is missing from nearest weather station I'd like it to go to the next nearest weather station and take the temp from there instead. So I can join the tables as you said, I can't figure out is how to check for a reading on every day of the year and if one is missing from the station at rank 1 then try the station at rank 2, and then 3 if needed so that every building has just one temp reading for every day

Comment: @GMcS How do you work out which is the "nearest" weather station? Building 1 is 5km from Station 1 but there is no data on how far Building 1 is from Stations 2, 3 or 4 (and geographically your data does not make sense as the stations are all in London but Glasgow, Manchester and Birmingham are all more than 18km from London).

Comment: Those are just random data. I've done a spatial join using actual geometry columns so that the table has each building ID and then details of the 3 nearest weather stations.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to do something like here:
SAMPLE DATA

```sql
WITH
    buildings (B_ID, B_TYPE, B_DESC, B_LOC) AS
        (
            Select 1, 'House', 'Terrace', 'London' From Dual Union All
            Select 2, 'Appartments', '5 Floors', 'Manchester' From Dual Union All
            Select 3, 'Office', '12 Floors', 'Birmingham' From Dual Union All
            Select 4, 'Workshop', 'Detached', 'Glasgow' From Dual 
        ),
    stations (S_ID, S_DATE, S_TEMP, S_LOC) AS 
        (
            Select 1, DATE '2018-01-01', 1, 'London' From Dual Union All
            Select 2, DATE '2018-01-02', 1, 'London' From Dual Union All
            Select 3, DATE '2018-01-03', 2, 'London' From Dual Union All
            Select 4, DATE '2018-01-04', 1, 'London' From Dual 
        ),
    joins_tbl (B_ID, S_ID, DISTANCE, RANKED) AS
        (
            Select 1, 1, 5, 1 From Dual Union All
            Select 2, 2, 5, 1 From Dual Union All
            Select 3, 3, 12, 2 From Dual Union All
            Select 4, 4, 18, 3 From Dual 
        ),
```

First create CTE (I named it grid) that will construct rows having every building and in every date. The CTE also creates LOOKUP columns as an alternative station ID if self measuring didn't recorded. This part you should adjust to your data and preferences. Here is the grid:

```sql
    grid AS 
        (
            SELECT d.S_DATE "A_DATE", d.B_ID "BUILDING_ID", s.S_TEMP, s.S_ID,
                   (Select Min(S_ID) From joins_tbl Where B_ID <> d.B_ID And RANKED = 1) "LOOKUP_ID_1",
                   (Select Min(S_ID) From joins_tbl Where B_ID <> d.B_ID And RANKED = 2) "LOOKUP_ID_2",
                   (Select Min(S_ID) From joins_tbl Where B_ID <> d.B_ID And RANKED = 3) "LOOKUP_ID_3",
                   --
                   (Select MAX(S_ID) From joins_tbl Where B_ID <> d.B_ID And RANKED = 1) "LOOKUP_ID_4",
                   (Select MAX(S_ID) From joins_tbl Where B_ID <> d.B_ID And RANKED = 2) "LOOKUP_ID_5",
                   (Select MAX(S_ID) From joins_tbl Where B_ID <> d.B_ID And RANKED = 3) "LOOKUP_ID_6"
            FROM  (   Select  d.S_DATE, b.B_ID
                      From    stations d
                      Inner Join buildings b ON(1 = 1)
                  ) d
            INNER JOIN joins_tbl j ON(j.B_ID = d.B_ID)
            LEFT JOIN  stations s ON(s.S_DATE = d.S_DATE And s.S_ID = d.B_ID)
            
            ORDER BY d.B_ID, d.S_DATE
        )

--  R e s u l t :
A_DATE    BUILDING_ID     S_TEMP       S_ID LOOKUP_ID_1 LOOKUP_ID_2 LOOKUP_ID_3 LOOKUP_ID_4 LOOKUP_ID_5 LOOKUP_ID_6
--------- ----------- ---------- ---------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
01-JAN-18           1          1          1           2           3           4           2           3           4 
02-JAN-18           1                                 2           3           4           2           3           4 
03-JAN-18           1                                 2           3           4           2           3           4 
04-JAN-18           1                                 2           3           4           2           3           4 
01-JAN-18           2                                 1           3           4           1           3           4 
02-JAN-18           2          1          2           1           3           4           1           3           4 
03-JAN-18           2                                 1           3           4           1           3           4 
04-JAN-18           2                                 1           3           4           1           3           4 
01-JAN-18           3                                 1                       4           2                       4 
02-JAN-18           3                                 1                       4           2                       4 
03-JAN-18           3          2          3           1                       4           2                       4 
04-JAN-18           3                                 1                       4           2                       4 
01-JAN-18           4                                 1           3                       2           3             
02-JAN-18           4                                 1           3                       2           3             
03-JAN-18           4                                 1           3                       2           3             
04-JAN-18           4          1          4           1           3                       2           3
```

Now you could use COALESCE to get your missing data, and, if you want to know the station that is the source of displayed data, you could have it too. Here is the main SQL:

```
Select 
    A_DATE, BUILDING_ID, 
    COALESCE(S_TEMP,
              ( Select S_TEMP From stations Where S_DATE = g.A_DATE And S_ID = g.LOOKUP_ID_1  ),
                ( Select S_TEMP From stations Where S_DATE = g.A_DATE And S_ID = g.LOOKUP_ID_2  ),
                  ( Select S_TEMP From stations Where S_DATE = g.A_DATE And S_ID = g.LOOKUP_ID_3  ),
              ( Select S_TEMP From stations Where S_DATE = g.A_DATE And S_ID = g.LOOKUP_ID_4  ),
                ( Select S_TEMP From stations Where S_DATE = g.A_DATE And S_ID = g.LOOKUP_ID_5  ),
                  ( Select S_TEMP From stations Where S_DATE = g.A_DATE And S_ID = g.LOOKUP_ID_6  )
            ) "TEMP",
    COALESCE(CASE WHEN S_TEMP Is Not Null THEN 'SELF' END,
              ( Select 'LOOKUP_ID_1 - STATION ID = ' || S_ID From stations Where S_DATE = g.A_DATE And S_ID = g.LOOKUP_ID_1  ),
                ( Select 'LOOKUP_ID_2 - STATION ID = ' || S_ID From stations Where S_DATE = g.A_DATE And S_ID = g.LOOKUP_ID_2  ),
                  ( Select 'LOOKUP_ID_3 - STATION ID = ' || S_ID From stations Where S_DATE = g.A_DATE And S_ID = g.LOOKUP_ID_3  ),
              ( Select 'LOOKUP_ID_4 - STATION ID = ' || S_ID From stations Where S_DATE = g.A_DATE And S_ID = g.LOOKUP_ID_4  ),
                ( Select 'LOOKUP_ID_5 - STATION ID = ' || S_ID From stations Where S_DATE = g.A_DATE And S_ID = g.LOOKUP_ID_5  ),
                  ( Select 'LOOKUP_ID_6 - STATION ID = ' || S_ID From stations Where S_DATE = g.A_DATE And S_ID = g.LOOKUP_ID_6  )
            ) "SOURCE"
From 
    grid g

A_DATE    BUILDING_ID       TEMP SOURCE                                                            
--------- ----------- ---------- -------------------------------------------------------------------
01-JAN-18           1          1 SELF                                                                
02-JAN-18           1          1 LOOKUP_ID_1 - STATION ID = 2                                        
03-JAN-18           1          2 LOOKUP_ID_2 - STATION ID = 3                                        
04-JAN-18           1          1 LOOKUP_ID_3 - STATION ID = 4                                        
01-JAN-18           2          1 LOOKUP_ID_1 - STATION ID = 1                                        
02-JAN-18           2          1 SELF                                                                
03-JAN-18           2          2 LOOKUP_ID_2 - STATION ID = 3                                        
04-JAN-18           2          1 LOOKUP_ID_3 - STATION ID = 4                                        
01-JAN-18           3          1 LOOKUP_ID_1 - STATION ID = 1                                        
02-JAN-18           3          1 LOOKUP_ID_4 - STATION ID = 2                                        
03-JAN-18           3          2 SELF                                                                
04-JAN-18           3          1 LOOKUP_ID_3 - STATION ID = 4                                        
01-JAN-18           4          1 LOOKUP_ID_1 - STATION ID = 1                                        
02-JAN-18           4          1 LOOKUP_ID_4 - STATION ID = 2                                        
03-JAN-18           4          2 LOOKUP_ID_2 - STATION ID = 3                                        
04-JAN-18           4          1 SELF
```

Answer (score 0):

So in the end I created a new table which had one record for every building, and then the 3 nearest stations in the same row using outer joins so I could then filter on null values afterwards.

```
CREATE TABLE BUILD_STAT_LOOKUP AS
SELECT DISTINCT a.B_ID, b.STN AS STN_1, b.DISTANCE AS DISTANCE_1, c.STN AS STN_2, c.DISTANCE AS DISTANCE_2, d.STN AS STN_3, d.DISTANCE AS DISTANCE_3, e.STN AS STN_4, e.DISTANCE AS DISTANCE_4
FROM BUILD_STAT_JOIN a
FULL OUTER JOIN
(SELECT * FROM BUILD_STAT_JOIN WHERE N = 1) b
ON a.B_ID = b.B_ID
FULL OUTER JOIN
(SELECT * FROM BUILD_STAT_JOIN WHERE N = 2) c
ON a.B_ID = c.B_ID
FULL OUTER JOIN
(SELECT * FROM BUILD_STAT_JOIN WHERE N = 3) d
ON a.B_ID = d.B_ID
FULL OUTER JOIN
(SELECT * FROM BUILD_STAT_JOIN WHERE N = 4) e
ON a.B_ID = e.B_ID
;
```

Then made a new table selecting the first station that wasn't giving null temp readings using a case/when statement and first temp reading that wasn't null.

```
SELECT c1.MEAS_DATE, TO_CHAR(c1.MEAS_DATE, 'DDD') DOY, B_ID,
    CASE WHEN c1.STN IS NOT NULL THEN a.STN_1
    WHEN c2.STN IS NOT NULL THEN a.STN_2
    WHEN c3.STN IS NOT NULL THEN a.STN_3
    ELSE null
    END AS WEATHER_STATION_AVAIL,
    CASE WHEN c1.MIN_TEMP_C IS NOT NULL THEN c1.MIN_TEMP_C
    WHEN c2.MIN_TEMP_C IS NOT NULL THEN c2.MIN_TEMP_C
    WHEN c3.MIN_TEMP_C IS NOT NULL THEN c3.MIN_TEMP_C
    ELSE NULL
    END AS TMIN
FROM BUILD_STAT a
    FULL OUTER JOIN WEATHER_DATA c1
        ON a.STN_1 = c1.STN 
    FULL OUTER JOIN WEATHER_DATA c2
        ON a.STN_2 = c2.STN AND c1.MEAS_DATE = c2.MEAS_DATE
    FULL OUTER JOIN WEATHER_DATA c3
       ON a.STN_1 = c3.STN AND c1.MEAS_DATE = c3.MEAS_DATE
WHERE B_ID IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY a.B_ID, c1.MEAS_DATE, c1.STN, c2.STN, c3.STN, stn_1, stn_2, STN_3, c1.MIN_TEMP_C, c2.MIN_TEMP_C, c3.MIN_TEMP_C
ORDER BY B_ID, MEAS_DATE

;
```